DeviceSupport directory XCode 14.2 (iOS 17+)
Could someone please provide the Xcode iOS DeviceSupport files for iOS 17+ (especially 17.5)? I have Xcode 14.2 and can't update to 15+ because I have a MacBook Pro 2015. All the solutions I found online don't work for me. I need to create a basic WebApp and test it on my iPhone via USB, but I keep getting the error "Could not locate device support files." I searched for these files online and even downloaded Xcode 15, but they were not in the directory I downloaded. I would be very grateful for any help.
Thank you!
